# data not going from epic to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

if anyone of you see this i've a question i'm new to redux and i'm coming from angular and services logic so i kind of know how redux is working. I'm using only 2 epic listeners(one to call GET method from the service and one for POST) + services(for fetching data from an api). So whenever i've to call any api i make an object with some api configuration including url, param and if include authorization header in the api now the thing is this thing works fine when i dispatch one action at a time but when i've to do multiple actions means multiple get or post it stops in the epic after doing all the service and epic work and doesn't go to reducer to store the data and gives me error.
`Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`
I know there's something wrong in my implementation. It would be great if it works this way else i've to move to other services like thunk or something else.

```
 `
GetEpic = (action$) =>
            action$.ofType(Action.Get)
                .switchMap(({ payload }) => {
                    let { api, param, reqHeader, waitFor } = payload;
                    delete payload.api;
                    delete payload.param;
                    delete payload.reqHeader;
                    return HttpService.post(api, param, reqHeader, payload).then((userInfo) => {
                        if (userInfo.status && userInfo.status != 200) {
                            return {
                                type: 'ERROR'
                            }
                        }
                        return this.translateDataAndReturnType(userInfo, api, 'get', waitFor);
                    }).catch(() => {
                        return {
                            type: 'ERROR'
                        }
                    })
                })

translateDataAndReturnType(data, api, method, waitFor) {
        if (data && api) {
            this.count += 1;
            let actionInfo = this.routesData.find((d, i) => {
                return d.route == api
            })
            let routeAction = Object.assign({}, actionInfo);
            routeAction.payload = data;
            this.localDate[routeAction.route] = data;
            delete routeAction.route;
            if (typeof waitFor == 'number') {
                this.waitFor = waitFor;
                this.count = 0;
                this.count += 1;
            }
            if (this.count == this.waitFor) {
                routeAction.payload = this.localDate;
                if (this.actions) {
                    routeAction.type = this.actions;
                }
                return routeAction;
            }
        }
    }
`
```

**Updated with Answer**
What i was doing wrong is trying to get response of multiple action shot from my component at once which is not possible so i changed my strategy to use single action with multiple apis for that i created a json with a route and apis

```
`this.routeConfig = {
  "countriesCitesTimezone": [
                { route: 'countries', type: 'SUCCESS-COUNTRIES', param: '', reqHeader: false },
                { route: 'cities', param: '', reqHeader: false },
                { route: 'timezone', param: '', reqHeader: false }
            ]
}`
```

so whenever i have to call an action i calls the action with some configuration like

```
`var apiInfo = {
      route: 'countriesCitesTimezone',
      params: []
    }
    this.props.registration(apiInfo)`
```

which is then handled by epic

```
`GetEpic = (action$) =>
            action$.ofType(Action.Get)
                .switchMap(({ payload }) => {
                   let requests = this.routesConfig[payload.route];
                   return Observable.forkJoin(
                    requests.map((d, ind) => {
                        let param = d.param;
                        if (payload.params.length > 0) {
                            param = payload.params[ind];
                        }
                        return (HttpService.get(d.route, param, d.reqHeader));
                    })
                ).map((x) => {
                    console.log(x);
                    let result = {};
                    requests.map((d, ind) => {
                        result[d.route] = x[ind]
                    })
                    return ({
                        type: requests[0].type,
                        payload: result
                    })
                })
                })`
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: added code now the thing is if i do call the `Action.Get` multiple times with different configuration for `HttpService` then i get the error saying `Actions must be plain...`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap`.

`switchMap` will:

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.

So, when using `switchMap()`, every new action of type `Action.Get` will prevent the emission of previous service call's response if it is still pending.

Also, assuming your service call returns a `Promise`, you should consider wrapping the `HttpService.post()` call in [`Observable.fromPromise()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise). I believe the reason you are getting the `Actions must be plain objects...` error is because you are emitting a `Promise`, which is then dispatched to the store.